# Which smart bulbs support configurable power on bahaviour?

Tags: smart-lights

I just learned that Philips Hue now supports configurable power on behavior. The user can choose between off, on at default values or the last known setting.

This sounds very good because my wife is less enthusiastic about home automation than me, so she would really like to be able to turn on any light, to bright white setting, by flipping the switch (twice if needed).

Do any other bulbs also have this function?

Comment: You're probably going to have to add a bit more detail; what other requirements do you have for the bulbs? If Philips Hue has the feature you need, why exactly do you want an alternative?

Comment: @anonymous2: I'm not happy about the price of the Hue bulbs, that is the only thing. I will be happy if I can find a bulb that also works for me for half the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in addition to Phillips hue, WiZ (Phillips wifi) & Lifx (wifi) have this feature. All tuya-devices that are custom-flashed with tasmota also have this feature. Finally, all zigbee bulbs turn on with 100% brightness every time. However, only hubitat allows customization of this (using a hub-based driver), all other hubs make it so that it MUST come on when turned on. Some regular tuya (not flashed) lights also have this feature, but it will be a gamble.

WiZ is the most customizable overall, where it allows to change color, CT, and brightness on startup. LifX allows "power on" & "last state". Both of these bulbs have a dual-click function, where rapidly flicking the switch 2x gets you a different color/ct/brightness/on-or-off.

I hope this helped! Feel free to ask me more questions so that you can make the right choice.